# Error locating the element in selenium2

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium2.0  with testNG. While on using XPATH or CSS for element to locate its shows error “unable to locate the element” . 
I have programmed in Java as
below:

```
public class mytest {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public Alert alert;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://localhost:4503/xyz.html");

    }

    public static void clickButton(WebDriver driver, String identifyBy, String locator){
        if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
        }else if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
            driver.findElement(By.id(locator)).click();
        }else if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
            driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).click();
        }

    }

    public static void typeinEditbox(WebDriver driver, String identifyBy, String locator, String valuetoType){
        if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).sendKeys(valuetoType);
        }else if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
            driver.findElement(By.id(locator)).sendKeys(valuetoType);
        }else if (identifyBy.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
            driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).sendKeys(valuetoType);
        }

    }


    public static void openApplication(WebDriver driver, String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }






    @Test
    public void testAcrolinxApplication() throws InterruptedException {
        openApplication(driver,"http://xyz.com");
        typeinEditbox(driver,"name","p_user","xxx");
        typeinEditbox(driver,"name","p_pas","yyy");
        clickButton(driver,"id","input-submit");

/*Up to this its working fine …..

At below line this throws error could not locate the xpath element "//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em/span/span" BUT THIS IS WOKING FINE IN Selenium1.0 api that is with 
selenium.click("//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em/span/span"); */

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em/span/span")).click();




    }

}
```

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
to wait for some time, Noew its working.

Answer (score 1):

**Make Sure XPath/CSS Query is Correct**

Download something like [Firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) or anything else where you can test the XPath query  directly on the page. Once you know for sure that your query is correct, then you can narrow down the problem in Selenium.

**Narrow Down the Problem in Selenium**

For example, if your query `"//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em/span/span"` is not working, try the base of the query and see if Selenium finds it (don't worry about click for now). Increment from there until the error appears again.

Example:

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cq-gen100']"); //works?
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em"); //works?
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='cq-gen100']/em/span"); //works?
>   //etc

Comment: Thanks a lot @prestomanifesto, I will try this and get back on it. But is there any tool or method to find the correct XPATH or CSS to locate web-element.+1

Comment: Firebug can get you both the XPath and CSS paths of any element (right-click on element in the HTML tab and select Copy XPath or Copy CSS Path). However I recommend against this because the paths are very long and not at all flexible. Writing and debugging the paths by hand has worked better for me at least